# Do music playlists do live updating on iOS 13

Tags: ios, music

I have 3 playlists synced to my iPhone: The two regular playlists (as matches for the rules in this photo), as well as the smart playlist created by the rules in the photo. In other words, the smart playlist shown is a subset of other music that is synced to my iPhone.

Will the smart playlist with live updating enabled automatically update itself to contain 8 hours of music selected by least recently played without syncing to iTunes?

iOS 13.x

[image]

Update:
Seems to be a definite "Maybe".

I ran the playlist defined above 2 days in a row and got multiple repeats on the 2nd day of songs that were played on the 1st day.

The playlist is limited to 8hrs by least recently played of over 24hrs of available music. The playtime each day was less than 90 minutes.

This is what the playlist looked like on iOS 13's Music app. Perhaps the "Updated Yesterday" detail has something to do with it.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It is a maybe.

I have a smart playlist which I use heavily on my Mac

It does not even appear on my iPad or phone. Other smart playlists do.

This one is a smart playlist based off another playlist.

Thus playlists on iOS are less capable than on macOS and so you have to assume some info will be lost and check on eacxh playlist if they work.

Answer (score -1):

While I don't have a smart playlist with a limit of hours, I do have lots of smart playlists with various criteria. In my experience, **all of my smart playlists update automatically** on my iPhone and iPad.

Performing an action like playing a song which would add the song to the smart playlist makes the song appear in the smart playlist immediately for me as it would on macOS, even though the criteria can't be viewed or modified on iOS.

Comment: Odd none of my smart playlists update on iOS - does iOS have smart playlists?